# ios text input: cursor misplaced

Tags: html, ios, css, mobile-safari

I have a web app with a text input element:

```css
#sendmsg {
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid rgb(211, 211, 211);
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 3px 20px 3px 5px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0px;
  text-align: left;
  font: normal normal 400 normal 14px "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  color: #747373;
  height: 1.8em;
  width: 87%;
  background: #FEFEFE;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="sendmsg" name="chatmsg">
```

On iOS safari the input is displayed this way:
[image]

What can I do to resolve the misplaced cursor issue?

Comment: Use `line-height`

Comment: which ios version?

Comment: 11.6.2 version of ios.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug with Safari on iOS itself. Found some references to similar behavior: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=138201

It seems to be a symptom of having an input box inside of a container with overflow set to scroll. I was able to replicate the bug with just a very basic div with overflow: scroll, and an input in the middle of it and have not been able to find any clean css ways to fix it.

The two ways that would work to remove this bug are to remove the use of overflow scrolling on the main body of the page and either 1) have the header be sticky some other way, 2) let the header scroll along with the page on iOS. Are these options something we would want to do?